# Params Issue in WCF

Tags: wcf

I have created a WCF service in C# i am having error of no overload method adder takes 5 arguments please help.

Console Client

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {    
            Service1Client client = new Service1Client();
            int Result = client.adder(3, 44, 44, 4441, 11);           
        }
```

In Service1.svc

```
public int adder(params int[] no)
{
            int total = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < no.Length; i++)
            {
                total +=no[i];
            }
            return total;
}
```

In IService1.cs

```
[OperationContract]
int adder(params int[] no);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your service method expects an array of integer where as actually from your client you are sending individual integers.So there is clearly a compile time error would be thrown as your method expecting one type but you are sending different things.

you need to declare an int array

```
int[] no = new int[] { 3, 44, 44, 4441, 11 };
```

and you should pass this to your method.

```
client.adder(no);
```